# How to convert from sRGB to linear sRGB for computing the color correction matrix in opencv? (CCM)

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors

I have referred to the following [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221892/color-correction-matrix-in-lab-color-space-opencv) for computing the color correction matrix.

As referred in the thread mentioned above, I want to convert from the sRGB color space to linear sRGB space, I'm trying to use the [pwkit colorspace mapper](http://pydoc.net/pwkit/0.8.15/pwkit.colormaps/) code for the conversion.

However, i'm unsure about the resulting linear sRGB values, since the function requires sRGB in range [0-1], is dividing the sRGB values by 255.0, the correct approach? How to verify that the linear sRGB values returned by the function are correct?

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def srgb_to_linsrgb (srgb):
    """Convert sRGB values to physically linear ones. The transformation is
       uniform in RGB, so *srgb* can be of any shape.

       *srgb* values should range between 0 and 1, inclusively.

    """
    gamma = ((srgb + 0.055) / 1.055)**2.4
    scale = srgb / 12.92
    return np.where (srgb > 0.04045, gamma, scale)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    colorChecker = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Ai/Documents/Urine Sample Analysis/Assets/colorchecker_1.jpg')
    cc = cv2.cvtColor(colorChecker,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    plt.imshow(cc)

    #Convert srgb to linear rgb
    cc = cc / 255.0
    cc1 = srgb_to_linsrgb(cc)
    print("Conversion from sRGB to linear RGB:\n")
    print(cc1[1,1,:])
```

The result of conversion is: [0.30946892 0.23455058 0.19806932]

The input sRGB should be between 0-1, how to scale the value of sRGB channels from [0-255] to [0-1], would simple division by 255.0 result in correct linear sRGB values? How to verify that the conversion has resulted in correct linear sRGB values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From a terminology standpoint and assuming your image was effectively sRGB encoded, i.e. following IEC 61966-2-1:1999, you are decoding sRGB encoded non-linear light values by applying the sRGB Electro-Optical Transfer Function (EOTF), a type of colour component transfer function (CCTF) thus saying:

> I want to convert from the sRGB color space to linear RGB space

is not correct because you are still effectively using sRGB encoded colours, the only difference is that prior to using the decoding CCTF they were non-linearly encoded. An additive RGB colourspace is defined by a set of three components: primaries, whitepoint and CCTFs. By using the CCTF you have not changed at all the primaries or whitepoint, i.e. the gamut is the same, thus what you should say is more along those lines:

> I want to convert from the sRGB color space to linear sRGB color space

Now to verify that your approach is correct, you can compare with a reference implementation such as [Colour](https://github.com/colour-science/colour) whose code is used in the SO thread you referenced: 18% gray is 118 upon non-linear encoding using sRGB inverse EOTF:

```python
>>> int(round(colour.models.eotf_inverse_sRGB(0.18) * 255))
118
```

From there you can check if your method does convert back to 18% and it does (disregarding rounding)!

```
0.18116424424986022
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for clearing up a few important concepts, also for sharing about Colour lib, I have tried using my code and converting the 18% gray value (118,118,118) by first normalizing it ((118,118,118) / 255.0) and got the result : 0.18116424.