# Minimizing the error between the color checker reference values and the captured values using color correction matrix

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors

I want to compute a color correction matrix which can be used to adjust the [target (captured) image](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkC_5bbDpOcvaYem32XTmAWHrMU) to represent the most accurate colors regardless of the background lighting etc., to perform urine sample analysis. I have followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49221892/color-correction-matrix-in-lab-color-space-opencv) thread on SO to compute the color correction matrix (CCM).

For implementation, I have manually selected the ROI (24 colors patches) on the color checker board and computed the mean of each of the RGB channels, transformed it into linear RGB values from sRGB and performed linear regression (Ax = b) to estimate the transformation matrix, in our case the CCM.

After getting the CCM and multiplying it with the target RGB values, there is still a big difference between the actual reference values and the target values, Am I missing out on some crucial step for the calibration? How do I minimize the difference between the target and the actual values?

```
refRGB = np.array([[115, 82, 69],[204, 161, 141], [101, 134, 179], [89, 109, 61], [141, 137, 194], [132, 228, 208],
      [249, 118, 35], [80, 91, 182], [222, 91, 125], [91, 63, 123], [173, 232, 91], [255, 164, 26],
      [44, 56, 142], [74, 148, 81], [179, 42, 50], [250, 226, 21], [191, 81, 160], [6, 142, 172], 
    [252,252,252], [230,230,230], [200,200,200],[143,143,142], [100,100,100],[50,50,50]])

print(refRGB.shape)

def srgb_to_linsrgb (srgb):
    """Convert sRGB values to physically linear ones. The transformation is
    uniform in RGB, so *srgb* can be of any shape.

    *srgb* values should range between 0 and 1, inclusively.

    """
    gamma = ((srgb + 0.055) / 1.055)**2.4
    scale = srgb / 12.92
    return np.where (srgb > 0.04045, gamma, scale)

def linsrgb_to_srgb (linsrgb):
    """Convert physically linear RGB values into sRGB ones. The transform is
    uniform in the components, so *linsrgb* can be of any shape.

    *linsrgb* values should range between 0 and 1, inclusively.

    """
    # From Wikipedia, but easy analogue to the above.
    gamma = 1.055 * linsrgb**(1./2.4) - 0.055
    scale = linsrgb * 12.92
    return np.where (linsrgb > 0.0031308, gamma, scale)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    colorChecker = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Ai/Documents/Urine Sample Analysis/Assets/cc-china.jpg')
    cc = cv2.cvtColor(colorChecker,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    targetCC = cv2.imread('C:/Users/Ai/Documents/Urine Sample Analysis/Assets/cc-china.jpg')
    print(targetCC[1,1,0:3])

    dim = (800,700)
    targetCC = cv2.resize(targetCC,dim,interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
    fromCenter = False
    cv2.namedWindow('Select ROIs',1)
    cv2.imshow('Select ROIs',targetCC)
    ROIs = cv2.selectROIs('Select ROIs',targetCC,fromCenter)
    print("Target CC shape: ",targetCC.shape)
    targetValue = np.empty((0,3), int)

    for (idx,val) in enumerate(ROIs):
        ROI = targetCC[val[1]:val[1]+val[3], val[0]:val[0]+val[2],:]    
        print(ROI)
        channelMean = np.mean(ROI.reshape(-1,3),axis=0)
        targetValue = np.vstack((targetValue,channelMean))

    targetValue = targetValue.astype(int)
    print(targetValue.shape)
    targetValue[:,[0,2]] = targetValue[:,[2,0]] #BGR to RGB

    linTargetVal = targetValue/255.0
    linTargetVal = srgb_to_linsrgb(linTargetVal)

    normalizeRefVal = refRGB/255.0
    linRefVal = srgb_to_linsrgb(normalizeRefVal)
    ColorCorrectionMatrix = np.linalg.lstsq(linTargetVal,linRefVal,rcond=None)[0]

   print(ColorCorrectionMatrix)

   corrTargetVal = np.matmul(linTargetVal,ColorCorrectionMatrix)
   corrTargetVal = np.absolute(corrTargetVal)
   corrTargetVal = linsrgb_to_srgb(corrTargetVal)
   corrTargetVal = corrTargetVal * 255.0
   corrTargetVal = corrTargetVal.astype(int)
   print(corrTargetVal)
```

The result for corrected target and difference (reference - target):

```
    ----------Corrected SrGB----------------

[[139  99  85]
 [213 171 150]
 [121 152 195]
 [115 130  91]
 [171 178 205]
 [149 237 218]
 [232 113  74]
 [ 85  95 188]
 [220  97 113]
 [ 98  70 121]
 [194 233 120]
 [253 168  89]
 [ 54  57  89]
 [ 79 171  90]
 [205  66  86]
 [264 238 118]
 [207  97 150]
 [ 98 154 222]
 [205 208 195]
 [204 209 196]
 [165 171 161]
 [124 131 123]
 [ 81  83  78]
 [ 33  32  28]]
---------------------------------------

----------Difference----------------

[[-24 -17 -16]
 [ -9 -10  -9]
 [-20 -18 -16]
 [-26 -21 -30]
 [-30 -41 -11]
 [-17  -9 -10]
 [ 17   5 -39]
 [ -5  -4  -6]
 [  2  -6  12]
 [ -7  -7   2]
 [-21  -1 -29]
 [  2  -4 -63]
 [-10  -1  53]
 [ -5 -23  -9]
 [-26 -24 -36]
 [-14 -12 -97]
 [-16 -16  10]
 [-92 -12 -50]
 [ 47  44  57]
 [ 26  21  34]
 [ 35  29  39]
 [ 19  12  19]
 [ 19  17  22]
 [ 17  18  22]]
---------------------------------------
```